# EF 6.1.3 (ASP.NET 5 RC1 app) Async Repositories inconsistent results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC based Application using an async EF6 generic base repository which has a `GetAsync` method:

```
public virtual async Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, bool includeSoftDeleted = false) 
    {
        try
        {
            return 
                await
                    _context.Set<T>().Where(e => includeSoftDeleted || !e.IsDeleted).FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Unable to get the {typeof(T).Name}. See the exception for more details.",predicate,ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

All of my repositories use this class as base class and are injected with Autofac as `InstancePerLifetime()` in my services.

So I have a method in my service that calls this `GetAsync`:

```
 public async Task<int?> GetRoleAccessPermissionLevelAsync(UserRole userRole, Access access)
    {
        // TODO: Implement IEquatable for Access to replace with a == access
        var accessFromDb = await _accessRepository.GetAsync(a => a.Module == access.Module && a.Controller == access.Controller && a.Action == access.Action);

        if(accessFromDb == null) return null;

        var roleAccess = await _roleAccessRepository.GetAsync(r =>
           r.RoleId == userRole.RoleId && r.AccessId == accessFromDb.Id);

        return (int?)roleAccess?.AccessLevel;
    }
```

Here, the `accessFromDb` is sometimes `null`, sometimes not, with the same values given to it: `access.Module = "Main"`, Controller and action are `null`.

How is it possible that, without changing the `context` or the repository's `Set<T>()`, that this is sometimes `null` and sometimes returns the object?

I assume this has something to do with a 'lock' that I have to put somewhere for the async?

Comment: Your predicate is capturing a lot of variables and they appear to be reference types. How sound is your `==` logic?

Comment: How do you mean,how sound is it? What do you want me to give as extra information to chrck this?

Comment: Maybe you should try `a.Module.Id == access.Module.Id`

Comment: Ow yea, forgot to mention that module, controller and action are just string properties on the Access entity

Comment: Is EF generating identical queries everytime you test it?

Comment: Yes, it's always the same query:

Comment: Please, don't use MVC6 tags anymore. It's for a future version of ASP.NET MVC based on the old webstack (MVC5). ASP.NET Core is a complete new and incompatible, portable version based on .NET Core. Use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] and/or [tag:asp.net-core] tags instead